# Azure Web sites error: "Specified hostname is already reserved for another site "

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem adding my domain to azure web site.

Every time I try, it tells me "Specified hostname www.moblin.co.il is already reserved for another site"

I have a different site where I had that domain on but I deleted the domain from that site and now I am trying to add it to my other site.

I changed the DNS as I should have, but still no go.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Quite a lot of Azure operations are asynchronous. it's possible you may just have to wait a while for that name to become unreserved.

Comment: I know, and I've been waiting for more then 24 hours... still no change...

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?  If so, how?